# How to completely remove QGIS for clean reinstall Windows 10

Tags: qgis, installation

My initial install was Dufour 2.0 and have update to 2.18 and then recently to 3.4.  20 worked fine, but then 2.18 had some periodic crashes that were intermittent.  Now at 3.4 QGIS "hangs p" and I have to kill in the task manager.  I tried to uninstall everything for a clean start but somehow there are tidbits that remain and I now can't get any to work properly.  I've a 64 bit machine and have tried both 32 and 64 reinstall to no avail.

I purchased Ashampo uninstaller and tried that but still no complete uninstall.

Any idea?  I'm considering a complete wipe and reset but that is a huge headache and if there is an alternative I'll try it.

Answer (score 1):

OK, so I've run CCleaner, gone through the Registry looking for anything that has QGIS and deleting.  After reinstall QGIS 3.4 32 bit I still got a "hang up" after 3 or 4 clicks and have to kill it with the task manager.

Then I went to my startup list and disabled everything on the list.  Rebooted and now I'm good to go.  I realize that I didn't actually find what was in conflict but some other program must have had the resources that QGIS needed.  If over time it occurs again I'll try to isolate it and update which other program it was.  For now I'm just happy to be mapping again.

Short answer: If QGIS hangs up, try disabling all programs from starting at boot.

Answer (score 0):

Looks like you need to clean the registry to get rid of the remaining pieces. I've used CCleaner to clean my registry in the past, but there are several registry cleaners out there that can do the job. Also, you could do it from Windows' own Registry Editor. The basic idea is to search any string containing "qgis" and delete it.

Be very careful if you're not used to editing registries, though, for you could damage your OS and end up having to do exactly what you wanted to avoid, i.e. reinstalling Windows from scratch. There are tutorials about it all over the web, so you don't have to just try blindly.